# Magento2 - How to save custom field under admin_user table in database?

Tags: magento2, custom-field, admin-user

I have created a custom field in admin user creation form ,how to save that field in `admin_user` table in Magento2?

Comment: add your custom column to admin_user table to store your new  field. and field name and column name must be same.

Comment: @MrMakwana,Thanks for your reply ..but I have created the custom field like the way you explained above. On saving the admin user creation form , the value in custom field are not saved to the table admin_user

Comment: please share your save code to more clarification

Comment: I didn't write it .I'm asking about how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a new field(**telephone**) in the database table **admin_user** using the following.

> Vendor/Module/etc/db_schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="admin_user" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Admin User Table">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="telephone" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Admin User Telephone"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

> Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_admin_user_form" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Tab\Main" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Plugin/Block/Adminhtml/User/Edit/Tab/Main.php

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Tab;

    class Main
    {
        /**
         * Get form HTML
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function aroundGetFormHtml(
            \Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main $subject,
            \Closure $proceed
        )
        {
            $form = $subject->getForm();
            if (is_object($form)) {
                $fieldset = $form->getElement('base_fieldset');
                /** @var $model \Magento\User\Model\User */
                $model = $this->registry->registry('permissions_user');
                $data = $model->getData();
                $fieldset->addField(
                    'telephone',
                    'select',
                    [
                        'name' => 'telephone',
                        'label' => __('Select Telephone'),
                        'title' => __('Select Telephone'),
                        'options' => ['0' => __('--Select--'), '1' => __('Option 1'), '2' => __('Option 2'), '3' => __('Option 3')],
                        'class' => 'select',
                        'value' => isset($data['telephone']) ? $data['telephone'] : 0
                    ]
                );

                $subject->setForm($form);
            }

            return $proceed();
        }
    }
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: ,Thanks..Now Value is updated in the admin_user table, but the issue is the value is not reflected inthe admin user creation form.
I have created the select option field ,while saving the correct value is updated in the admin_user table but ,while viewing that user form the field displays default value

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check

Comment: Is worked for you?

Comment: Thank you so much @kishor .It was perfectly worked for me.It saves my time...Thanks again