# How to change custom UI grid collection based on custom attribute value in magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, admin-user, custom-admin-grid

I have created custom field in admin user creation form.Based on the value in this field,My custom module grid collection will  be loaded.How to acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is worked for me .I have changed by model file refering this https://webkul.com/blog/join-two-table-and-create-grid-in-admin-section-using-ui-component-in-magento2/ and then I have changed the _initSelect() instead of   joinleft I used   $this->getSelect()->where("main_table.user_id = ".$Id);

Answer (score 0):

**add this into your layout file**

```
<uiComponent name="admin_user_listing"/>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="admin_user_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">admin_user</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/admin_user_listing.xml**

**admin_user_listing.xml**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">admin_user_listing.admin_user_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">admin_user_listing.admin_user_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Post</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="nameOfDataSource">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">admin_user_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">user_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">user_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">user_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="user_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="firstname">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">First Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

for more [click here](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html)

***Note: it's basically created on your previous question [click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304971/magento2-how-to-save-custom-field-under-admin-user-table-in-database)***

Comment: I have already created one custom grid.It has column which I was created customly in admin creation form.based on that Customly created field in admin creation form my custom grid Collection will be filter.
for example my custom admin form field value is 1,then in my custom grid only the rows which has custom admin form field value is 1 will be shown.Other than that all other rows are hidden